# Understanding Python Multiprocessing Documentation

Tags: python, multiprocessing, documentation

Trying to understand Python multiprocessing documents. 
I would put this on meta but I'm not sure whether it might be valuable to searchers later.

I need some guidance as to how these examples relate to multiprocessing.

***Am I correct in thinking that multiprocessing is using multiple processes (and thus CPUs) in order to break down an iterable task and thus shorten its duration?***

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def f(name):
    print('hello', name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

***We are starting one process; but how do I start multiple to complete my task? Do I iterate through Process + start() lines?***

Yet there are no examples later in the documentation of for example:

```
for x in range(5):
    p[x]=Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p[x].start()
p.join()
```

Would that be the 'real life' implementation?

*Here is the 'Queue Example':*

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def f(q):
    q.put([42, None, 'hello'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue()
    p = Process(target=f, args=(q,))
    p.start()
    print(q.get())    # prints "[42, None, 'hello']"
    p.join()
```

***But again, how is this multiprocessing? This is just starting a process and having it run objects in a queue?
How do I make multiple processes start and run the objects in the queue?***

Finally for pool:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(processes=4) as pool:         # start 4 worker processes
        result = pool.apply_async(f, (10,)) # evaluate "f(10)" asynchronously in a single process  
        print(result.get(timeout=1))        # prints "100" unless your computer is *very* slow
```

**Are four processes doing 10x10 at once and it waits until all four come back or does just the one do this because we only gave the pool one argument? 
If the former: Wouldn't that be slower than just having one do it in the first place? What about memory? Do we hold process 1's result until process 4 returns in RAM or does it get printed?**

```
        print(pool.map(f, range(10)))       # prints "[0, 1, 4,..., 81]"
        it = pool.imap(f, range(10))
        print(next(it))                     # prints "0"
        print(next(it))                     # prints "1"
        print(it.next(timeout=1))           # prints "4" unless your computer is *very* slow
        result = pool.apply_async(time.sleep, (10,))
        print(result.get(timeout=1))        # raises multiprocessing.TimeoutError
```

Comment: "_I would put this on meta but..._" Good choice that you put it here instead. Meta isn't really about "questions about topics one level removed from programming, for example documentation", it's more like "questions about the workings and policy of Stack Overflow", so this question wouldn't fit too well there.

Comment: Please elaborate more what you are trying to achieve as this looks more like a critique against the documentation rather than a question. All the above mentioned example are making use of `multiprocessing`, what is that is not clear?

Comment: I genuinely don't know what is going on! I'll put the question in bold